# In IntelliJ, how to auto-import rxjs operators from 'rxjs/operators' i.s.o. 'rxjs/internal/operators'?

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, rxjs, webstorm, rxjs6

Rxjs pipeable operators should be imported from 'rxjs/operators', e.g.

```
import {catchError, filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

However, when using IntelliJ's auto-import, the import statement that is generated is like so:

```
import {catchError, filter, map} from 'rxjs/internal/operators';
```

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The only correct way is using `rxjs/operators`. Avoid importing anything under `rxjs/internal/*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider upgrading to the most recent IDEA version - [WEB-32299](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32299) should be fixed there

Answer (score 3):

There's a catch for projects created in the old days. IntelliJ actually has a configuration to control what packages **should not be used as imports**.

However, configuration of old projects may consist 'rxjs', this is why the internal packages were suggested.

Review the configuration in your settings: Editor > Code Style > Typescript > **"Do not import exactly from"**

[image]

Disclaimer, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1

Comment: This was it for me, just removed the "rxjs/Rx" from the list and auto import can now properly resolve "of", "forkJoin", etc..